# Uniqueness requirement for asset symbols

Tags: assets

From my understanding symbols exist within Stellar accounts, in other words each account is a distinct namespace for symbols.

In [this example](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/issuing-assets.html) there could be thousands of distinct "AstroDollars" asset types that would share nothing in common except for the symbol, provided that they were each issued by distinct accounts.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. Each asset on the ledger is unique and identified by 3 parameters:

- Code
- Issuer address
- Type (`alphanum4` or `alphanum12`)

XLM itself is a special asset with type `native`.